# Browser window with fixed tabs as a separate application?

Tags: browser, tabs, workflow, node-webkit

Ok, this may sound as a very strange question, but nevertheless.

What I want is to have a separate browser application (on mac) with some fixed set of tabs that will be reseted on each start of this app. For example, I use a bunch of web applications for work (gitlab, toggle, forge, etc) and I want to use them separately from other sites, in separate application.

Can this be achieved with any browser, or maybe quickly built with some SDK or in any other way?

For now the most close thing I've found is this: http://www.sitepoint.com/tabbed-browser-node-webkit-angularjs/
But the approach.. You use a single webview, fake tabs in js and use iframe to display content. It should work, but I wonder, if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different profiles on chrome and set them up to start up with the list of tabs you need for each profile.

each profile is virtually a sandbox with it's own storage cookies sessions etc, so you can have different user logins for each profile.

It'll look something like this:
Create a desktop shortcut that will point to chrome, stating the profile and the list of websites you want to open by default (separated with spaces):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Default" https://google.com https://gmail.com

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1" https://github.com https://twitter.com
```

You can find your chrome profile directories in:

```
%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

Comment: oh, that's interesting. do you know how to do this on mac?

Comment: @Terion yes you can find how to do it on OSX here: http://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile